# Stopword removal with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, stop-words

I would like to remove stopwords from a column of a data frame.
Inside the column there is text which needs to be splitted.

For example my data frame looks like this:

```
ID   Text
1    eat launch with me
2    go outside have fun
```

I want to apply stopword on `text column` so it should be splitted.

I tried this:

```
for item in cached_stop_words:
    if item in df_from_each_file[['text']]:
        print(item)
        df_from_each_file['text'] = df_from_each_file['text'].replace(item, '')
```

So my output should be like this:

```
ID   Text
1    eat launch 
2    go fun
```

It means stopwords have been deleted.
but it does not work correctly. I also tried vice versa in a way make my data frame as series and then loop through that, but iy also did not work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your expected output for that?

Comment: thanks for the comment, I updated the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` (by itself) isn't a good fit here, because you want to perform *partial* string replacement. You want regex based replacement.

One simple solution, when you have a manageable number of stop words, is using `str.replace`.

```
p = re.compile("({})".format('|'.join(map(re.escape, cached_stop_words))))
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.lower().str.replace(p, '')

df
   ID               Text
0   1       eat launch  
1   2   outside have fun
```

If performance is important, use a list comprehension.

```
cached_stop_words = set(cached_stop_words)
df['Text'] = [' '.join([w for w in x.lower().split() if w not in cached_stop_words]) 
    for x in df['Text'].tolist()]

df
   ID              Text
0   1        eat launch
1   2  outside have fun
```

Comment: Thank you so much , it worked except can you please also apply lower on that. like mg and MG should be treated the same